# Why does the getPrototypeOf() return incorrect constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var protoRabbit = {size: "small"};
var fastRabbit = Object.create(protoRabbit);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(fastRabbit));
```

The above snippet prints:

> Object { size: "small" }

Shouldn't this print protoRabbit {size: "small"} instead? What am i missing in my understanding?

Comment: The variable name "protoRabbit" has nothing to do with the object itself. It's just a variable that happens to hold a reference to the object. Objects do not have intrinsic names.

Comment: Do `console.log(protoRabbit)` and it will print the same.

Answer (score 6):

The name that is printed in front of the object is the name of the constructor function. Your object `protoRabbit` has the constructor `Object`, because you create this object, using an object literal:

```
var protoRabbit = {size: "small"};
```

If you want this object to have a different constructor, you have to use your own constructor function:

```
function Constr() {
    this.size = "small";
}
var protoRabbit = new Constr();
var fastRabbit = Object.create(protoRabbit);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(fastRabbit)); //Constr { size: "small" }
```

**EDIT**

I have to agree with Demurgos' answer, that the result of `console.log(obj);` depends on the browsers implementation. So it can be different from browser to browser and can (apparently) sometimes even vary within one browser ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038102/does-object-createproto-modify-proto-indicated-by-chrome-output)).

Comment: I ran this snippet on chrome (version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit)) using Mac 10.10 and I got the following output. Object {size: "small"}

Comment: @Harish That is very interesting. To be honest, I don't know what is happening here, because if you log protoRabbit, directly after its creation, the output is as expected. It only changes after executing `Object.create`. I opened up a [follow up question](http://jsfiddle.net/L5eahaLf/) for this topic. I also think I have to rather agree with `Demurgos` that the output depends on the implementation and that it varies from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1):

The name displayed in the console is not standard. It is up to each browser to provide the best context in their console when printing an object. The fact is that the objects contains the right properties, and that's all we really need.