# Does Object.create(proto) modify proto (indicated by Chrome output)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototype

The following script puzzles me a little:

```
function A() {
}

var a = new A();

console.log(a);  //A {}

Object.create(a);

console.log(a);  //Object {}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L5eahaLf/)

So apparently `Object.create()` alters somehow the object, that is passed to it. However, I cannot see any difference.

So what is happening? Why is the output of `console.log()` different in both cases?

*Remark:* I only noticed this in Chrome. In Firefox, the output seems to be always `Object {}`. Not sure about other browsers.

Comment: I would wager its related to how chrome does static analysis. By using `Object.create` you are altering its preconceived notions of what type object a is. Rather than altering the object, you are just nullifying chrome's ability to auto-detect that it is of type 'A'